# Cannot turn script back on

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've got an issue. When `(Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)`, `Speedy` script is disabled, thus we cannot enable it again from inside the script like shown below. How can we go around this?

```
public class  Speedy : MonoBehaviour {

GameObject car;

 if (speed == good)
    {
        GameObject car = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Car");

        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) 
        {
            car.GetComponent<Speedy>().enabled = false;
        }

        else car.GetComponent<Speedy>().enabled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your code is wrong: it has to be inside a void Update()

Comment: @xoxox That was just an example to demonstrate the issue that I'm encountering.

Comment: Even examples should be of correct format. C# does not allow an if statement outside a method.

Answer (score 1):

When disabled, a script wont run anymore and therefore you cannot enable it from the same script again (of course you could create a background thread which keeps it running, that would be a terrible solution).

Create a separate script called `SpeedyEnabler`, that enables the `Speedy` script on mouse click and add it to the GameObject.

Alternatively, declare a field `isEnabled` in `Speedy`, replace `this.enabled` by `isEnabled` and perform the desired actions when `isEnabled` is `true`.

If your script simply is supposed to act on input, enabling and disabling the script is not a good idea anyway. Instead, call a method from the input controller to act...

Comment: Disabled script will not receive unity events(Update, FixedUpdate etc ). It doesn't mean that it can't perform any actions. So script can enable itself

Comment: Well how would perform any actions without any incoming events? The only way is to call a method from another script. I am going to update my answer later.

Comment: you should use design pattern similar to MVC, input and controllers should be in different classes, that will pay off when your game grow in complexity.